# Array.from for array-of-objects. How to uniquely id each object?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to create an array that contains Nx duplicates of an input array-of-objects, and assign a unique ID to each individual object in the output array.

I know I can do the initial duplication, like so...

```
let input = [ { type: 123, name: 'apples'} , { type: 456, name: 'pears'} ]
let output = [ ...Array.from( {length: 3}, () => (input)) ].flat(1)
```

to get me..

```
[ { id: 123, name: 'apples'} , { id: 456, name: 'pears'}, { id: 123, name: 'apples'} , { id: 456, name: 'pears'}, { id: 123, name: 'apples'} , { id: 456, name: 'pears'} ]
```

but I don't know how, as part of that `Array.from` step, to add a unique ID to each object?

*(Since each input object has it's own `type`, which is unique, I'd like to just combine that with it's set number, e.g. for the 1st & 3rd elements it's uniqueID would be `123-0`, `123-1`)*

I know how to acheive it with for loops...

```
let output = []
  for (let i=0; i<N; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < input.length; j++) {
      let newObject = { ...input[j] }
      newObject.id = newObject.field1.ID+'-'+j
      output.push(newObject)
    }
  }
```

but I'd like to learn how I could achieve the same whilst using Array.from, or some other similar function?

Comment: output.forEach((o, i) => o.id = i + 1);

Comment: this is a nice idea @Bharat and is what I first reached for too!  But it doesn't work. :(

It will set the id on all matching duplicated objects to be the value of the *last* object it finds.

e.g. we have three `{apples}` in the example I gave.  The index from `.forEach` will return all three apples set to 5 (the final position), and all three Pears set to 6...
```
{ "id": 5, "name": "apples" },
{ "id": 6, "name": "pears" },
{ "id": 5, "name": "apples" },
{ "id": 6, "name": "pears" },
{ "id": 5, "name": "apples" },
{ "id": 6, "name": "pears" } ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The callback argument of [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) is passed a collection element (which is `undefined` in your example) and an index. You can then [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over `input` and combine the *type* of each element with the current "set" index

```js
let input = [ { type: 123, name: 'apples'} , { type: 456, name: 'pears'} ];

let output = Array.from(
  { length: 3 },
  (_, i) => input.map((item) => ({ id: `${item.type}-${i}`, ...item }))
).flat(1);

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?retiredLocale=it) function

```js
let output = [ ...Array.from( {length: 3}, () => (input)) ].flat(1).map((a, idx) => a = {...a, id: a.name.ID + '-' + idx})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `callback` function of the `Array.from` method to update the `type`. Check it out-

```js
const input = [{type: 123, name: 'apples'} , {type: 456, name: 'pears'}];

const output = Array.from( {length: 3}, (_, i) => {
  return input.map(item => ({...item, id: `${item.type}-${i}`}));
}).flat();

console.log(output);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height: 100%!important; top: 0}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively: a somewhat more generic multiplier function

```js
const initial = [{
  type: 123,
  name: 'apples'
}, {
  type: 456,
  name: 'pears'
}];
const multiply = (initialArray, n = 3, serialKey = `type`) => 
  [].concat(...[...Array(n)]
    .map( (_, i) => 
      initialArray.map( v => ({ ...v, [serialKey]: `${v[serialKey]}-${i}` }) ) )
  );

console.log(multiply(initial, 4));
```